# AngularJS ng-controller not working after bootstraping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I add ng-controller to any div, the `{{ }}` are rendered as such.

```
<div id="1">
<div class="ExplorerApp">  
    <div>
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
        <br>
        Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
    </div>
    <div class="NavigationPane" ng-controller="ExplorerController">
        <div>Pane data: {{myData.test}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The first div works fine but the second one doesn't. Following is my js code:

```
        var app = angular.module('Explorer', []);
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("1"), ["Explorer"]);

        app.controller("ExplorerController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.myData = {};
            $scope.myData.test = "Hello Angular";
        });
```

Comment: What element should return this: `document.getElementById(self._compID)` ?

Comment: @TeoMor update the code it contains the id only of div

Comment: The ID is `1`, not `#1`. Terrible ID value btw

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13906/

Comment: @TeoMor OP doesn't have `ng-app`

Comment: @TeoMor I can't use ng-app due to complexity of my web app  -lazy loading etc.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, this should do the work: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13907/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems.

The first one is the id selector supplied for `getElementById` is incorrect, it should be without `#` character (and better to avoid numeric ids, although it would also work). Or if you use `#1` you can go with `document.querySelector('#1')`.

The second problem is that you need to bootstrap the app *after* module and all services and controllers are created. In your case you were doing `create app -> bootstrap -> create controller`, while it should be `create app -> create controller -> bootstrap`.

Correct code:

```
var app = angular.module('Explorer', []);
app.controller("ExplorerController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.test = "Hello Angular";
});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("1"), ["Explorer"]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/eTvbTkUeFkDj0Bkye0qc?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a ton! bootstrapping at the end fixed the issue

Comment: Tnx that solution help me as well

Answer (score -1):

Use `ng-app="Explorer"`.

index.html

```
<div ng-app = "Explorer">
  <div class="ExplorerApp">  
    <div>
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
        <br>
        Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
    </div>
    <div class="NavigationPane" ng-controller="ExplorerController">
        <div>Pane data: {{myData.test}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('Explorer', []);
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById(self._compID), ["Explorer"]);

        app.controller("ExplorerController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.myData = {};
            $scope.myData.test = "Hello Angular";
        });
```

Look my code in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/parthipans/5DMjt/1453/